# Drupal 6 to 7; returning keys instead of label

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-theming, drupal-fields

I recently upgraded from Drupal 6 to 7 and on my node pages it is now returning the keys for each selected custom field, instead of the label. This is only happening for "Select list" fields.

For example, the field "Price" is entered as "ForSale|This property is for sale now" in the custom field, and it is showing "ForSale" on the page instead of "This property is for sale now". The node template is showing these fields by:

I just need to simply get it to show the label again, instead of the key. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I noticed when I added a new custom field that it would display correctly, so I will reenter the existing ones, not an answer, but a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Go to phpMyAdmin or another database management tool and run this SQL query:

```
update `field_config_instance` set data = replace(data,'s:13:"display_label";i:0;','s:13:"display_label";i:1;') WHERE field_name like 'field_machine_name';
```

Replace `field_machine_name` with the machine name of your field.

Then clear the cache and it should be working. Remember to make a backup before this changes.